# Database count column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have two tables:

```
"sites" has_many "users" 
"users" belongs_to "sites"
```

Is it better that whenever a **users** got added to **sites** I added column called **users_count** in sites table and increment it by one. Or is doing a conditional count on users table the best way?

Comment: It depends on what you're up to.

Comment: if the count's being done MANY times, then it'd make sense to store a cached value. But low traffic/low query-rate, the extra overhead might not be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Better" is a subjective term.

However, I'll be adamant about this. There should not be two sources of the same information in a database, simply because they may get out of step.

The definitive way to discover how many users belong to a site is to use `count` to count them.

Third normal form requires that every non-key attribute depends on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key (so help me, Codd).

If you add a user count to sites, that does *not* depend solely on the `sites` key value, it also depends on information in other tables.

You *can* revert from third normal form for performance if you understand the implications and mitigate the possibility of inconsistent data (such as with triggers) but the vast majority of cases should remain 3NF.